# Does JPQL have a "SUBSET" function

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have a simple data model as follows:

- Entity 1: EmployeeAsset. This has a reference to an Employee object.
- Entity 2: EmployeeJobPosition. This also has a reference to an Employee. It also has a reference to a JobPosition (this is another entity class) object which in turn contains a collection of OrganisationUnitEntry (this is another entity class) objects.

As a parameter, I have a collection of OrganisationUnitEntry objects that the user selected (let's call this ouEntries). I need a query that would return all EmployeeAsset objects that are related to a JobPosition that has an OrganisationUnitEntry collection on it that is a superset of ouEntries (i.e. ouEntries is a subset of ...jobPosition.organisationUnitEntries).

So the query could be built dynamically with something like:

```
SELECT ea
FROM EmployeeAsset ea, EmployeeJobPosition ejp
WHERE ea.employee = ejp.employee
AND :orgUnitEntry1 MEMBER OF ejp.jobPosition.organisationUnitEntries
...
AND :orgUnitEntryN MEMBER OF ejp.jobPosition.organisationUnitEntries
```

(where orgUnitEntry1 - N are just the elements in ouEntries).

However a subset type function would be a lot neater and then I could put this in a static / named query which I usually prefer. Something like

```
...
AND :ouEntries SUBSET OF ejp.jobPosition.organisationUnitEntries
```

Any ideas about how best to write such a query?

Comment: what does the JPA spec say?

Comment: I couldn't find anything about a SUBSET function, which is why I am asking :) It may also not just be a single function, I am just looking for an alternate / better way to generate the dynamic query that I gave in my example in a static way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use an IN?

```
SELECT ea
FROM EmployeeAsset ea, EmployeeJobPosition ejp join ejp.jobPosition.organisationUnitEntries o
WHERE ea.employee = ejp.employee
AND o IN :ouEntries
```

Depending on your JPA provider, you may need to compare the ids with the IN instead of the objects.
EclipseLink should allow you to compare objects (>=2.4).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion James. I can give this a try. It would just need to change to "AND :ouEntries IN o" surely since I want to check if ouEntries is a subset of ejp.jobPosition.organisationUnitEntry? FYI: I use the latest version of Hibernate so I will have to see how it handles this. Thanks again.